# The term 'firebase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to host my react project with firebase  i'm facing error

```
firebase : The term 'firebase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ firebase login
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (firebase:String) [], CommandNotFoundException   
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried all the solutions :

- adding path to environment variable
- used command to install firebase      npm install firebase ,npm install -g firebase-tools, firebase login

Note: it's showing my  login id in command prompt but not in VS code editor only shows the above one

is there anything wrong in vs code?

the above one is my project folder structure help me which path is perfect  to use these commands

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this error yesterday. After following all the solutions available on the internet and working to solve it for hours, finally I fixed it. Here's the solution.

open cmd/power shell as administrator then enter the following command,
npm ls -g --depth=0

you'll get a result like this,
C:\Users\sibam.npm-global
├── firebase-tools@13.0.3
├── firebase@10.7.2
├── jshint@2.13.6
└── npm@10.3.0

copy the first line path, search for 'edit the system environment variables' on windows start -> environment variables -> under user variables select PATH -> edit -> New -> pate the path -> ok -> ok

Restart your terminal, if you're inside any folder then enter cd/
Then enter, cd (your copied npm path)
Then enter firebase.cmd login
Then login to firebase if you are not logged in already.

Now you can go to your app/website's folder on terminal and enter Firebase. It should be working. But it's also possible that you'll get another error like this,

firebase : File C:\Users\sibam.npm-global\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- firebase
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Now this has 2 solutions.

1. run firebase.cmd
   or
   2)run Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
   then run firebase
   Now it'll work.
   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing and restarting all your terminals. Also, close and restart VS code. Often times, terminals don't pick up the changes until restarted.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, after doing that also I get the same error